# Does this question fit ServerFault more than SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I just asked [a question](https://superuser.com/q/1088603/63476) about Windows shell scripting in SuperUser, but I suddenly realised it may suits ServerFault better. Is this the case? How can I move it over? close/delete and re-post?

Answer (score 4):

I think SU is a good place for this. It wouldn't necessarily be off-topic here, but this has an end-user vibe about it, not a system administration one (remember, SF is for professional system administration, end user/home use questions are [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)).

But thanks for taking the time to ask this.

Comment: Make sense, I must admit I'm not a system administrator. But I was thinking that the scripts involved is more administration related rather than end-user? (I was trying to archiving service log files automatically with this script, like any sys admin will do, and how many end use will use this kind of script to move file?)

Comment: @Bolu The difference here is less in the activity, and more in the spirit and scope of the activity. As Sven said, it would probably fit here as well, it just fits slightly better in SU due to the context.

Comment: @Reaces, I see. If I add *I'm a system admin and was trying to automatically archive historical service log into another folder to free up spaces on the server* in the beginning of the question, will it fits slightly better here?

Comment: @Bolu Maybe, probably, but it is kind of irrelevant. For this kind of question you are equally likely to get an answer on SU or on ServerFault. In fact a lot of cross-over exists between the people that answer on SU and SF. So you might just get an answer from the same person on both sites.

Comment: @Reaces, that is my major concern. Many thanks!